# Google Spreadsheet API

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-sheets

I am am having some problems with the Google API. I am trying to find a way to link my search box to my spreadsheet, So when a user enters a query in my search box, It will search my Google Spreadsheet for that link - Is it even possible?  If anyone could help me out, I'll be greatfull.

Answer (score 1):

It is posible. You could try it with the URL Query Language and the apps script URLFetch service.
That way you can even use SQL like statements.

For info see:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Other option would just be to retrieve a range an parse the array for your search query.